# How to connect sql server when it deny connecting with windows authentication?

Tags: sql-server-2008, authentication

I had SQL Server 2008 R2 that it was in Windows Authentication mode. but recently I can not connect ! . does any services of SQL Server disabled ? or any feature ?

What should I do ?

The sql server services are running.

What I have done:

I execute this query:

```
 ALTER DATABASE mydatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
 /// and create a database.
```

I think I must alter it to MULTI_USER after doing my stuf. But I didn't :(.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use mixed mode authentication i.e. Sql Servier and Windows Authentication mode.

Right click on your Server for eg. hostname\SQLEXPRESS then select property. **Server property** window will appear then select **Security tab**. In Security tab check **server authentication.**

Comment: the problem is . HOW to connect and do this stuf?

Comment: what error message did you get? Have you check service is running properly or not?

Comment: I cannot connect to database either the SQL Server Management Studio or my programs. the error is : `cannot connect to hamed-pc, log in failed for user hamed-pc\hamed

Answer (score 0):

Windows Authentication Mode can not be disabled on SQl Server. You can check, whether sql service browser and other sql server services are running or not from Services.msc.

Comment: they're running. I have checked them before